# How to port ARRAY_AGG with mulitple arguments in Postgresql to Snowflake

Tags: postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake supports [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html) but it can take only parameter while [Postgresql's version](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) supports multiple.

I need to port the following snippet in Posgresql to Snowflake:

```
ARRAY_AGG(state, city, zipcode)
```

where state, city and zipcode are fields in one of my tables.

Any workaround? I know I can create 3 separate fields but that's not desired.

Comment: what are you trying? The array_agg() aggregate function does not support multiple parameters. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e1345445ef24e8fd2accb15f71a6a58b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending if you are want an Array of Array's or an Array of Objects

```
WITH r AS (
    SELECT column1 AS A, column2 AS B FROM (VALUES (1,'A'),(14,'B'),(35,'C'),(91,'D'),(105,'E'))
)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(a,b)) FROM r;
```

gives:

```
[ [ 1, "A" ],  [ 14, "B" ], [ 35, "C" ], [ 91, "D" ], [ 105, "E" ] ]
```

or

```
WITH r AS (
    SELECT column1 AS A, column2 AS B FROM (values (1,'A'),(14,'B'),(35,'C'),(91,'D'),(105,'E'))
)
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('A',a,'B',b)) FROM r;
```

gives:

```
[ { "A": 1, "B": "A" }, { "A": 14, "B": "B" }, { "A": 35, "B": "C" }, { "A": 91, "B": "D" }, { "A": 105, "B": "E" } ]
```

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/array_agg.html
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/array_construct.html
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/object_construct.html